# AngularJs promises: can you use both success and then?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I feel this is a very bad idea as i do not find it anywhere but testing it on my localhost it seems to work. I have a service :

```
angular
    .module('trips.services')
    .service('Trip', Trip);

function Trip($http, $q) {
    //.....

    function create(data) {
        var api_url = "/api/trip";
        return $http.post(api_url, data).success(function(data) {
            mixpanel.track("Trip: created", {}); // track that a new event happened
        });
    }
}
```

I also have a controller where i do something like:

```
Trip.create(data).success(function(data) {
    //do something after the trip is created
})
```

Now as you can see in this example I use both the **then promise** and the **success** callback in the service. If i do breakpoints in the debugger the success callback from the service is executed first and then the then clause from the controller. And it is also great for code organization, the common things i do after the service is successful is in the service while the specific things are in the controller. The thing is, i feel it is very non-according to any documentation or examples. Did not really find it somewhere, I discovered it by mistake. It might not work in some cases also?

I know the other options also, the $q library and could deffer in the service but that ends up in much more code.

So, is this a bad idea and why? Any opinions would be very helpful. I do not want to set up a wrong practice.

Comment: You can use both success and then, however, .success is deprecated and therefore shouldn't be used, so... just use .then. You can use .then multiple times.

Comment: Promises can be chained as many times as you like with `.then()` also you can return a promise chain from a `.then()`. the parent won't resolve untill the child chain has fully resolved. There is nothing wrong with pre-processing your data in your service then returning the promises. It is good for error handling also. `.then()` takes two arguments, on success CB and on error. However you can also use `.catch()` instead to make things look simpler. Don't forget angular is built upon the promise system.

Comment: thanks and good point on catch, i saw it several places and will start using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily a bad idea, it's just you using chaining of promises.

The `.then` function looks like this:

```
.then(function(success){}, function(error){});
```

you can see that `.success` is just shorthand for the first function above (as if you didn't declare the error callback).

Seeing as the promise can be passed around or maybe you have multiple services making the same request and you want just one promise created, then you might like to declare callbacks from multiple areas yet have just one promise resolve.

So is it a bad idea? No. Why? It is a flexible piece of code which is really up to the programmer to use. Can you declare multiple thens? Yes. Should you mix it with success callbacks? You can, but you might just want to stick to one style for consistency. But thats really up to what you're trying to achieve.

Angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
(Watch out for deprecation, might just want to stick to .then)

Answer (score 2):

Using promises consequently is considered a good practice as you already know. To do that, you can simply replace your `success`-callback with another `then`:

```
function create(data) {
    var api_url = "/api/trip";

    var promise = $http.post(api_url, data);

    promise.then(function(data) {
        mixpanel.track("Trip: created", {}); // track that a new event happened
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Having multiple independent `.then()`s on one promise is perfectly fine and works as you would expect.